# PreparedStatement issue in postgresql (select query)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, postgresql

I am trying to use the prepared statement in place of simple statement execution. when I run the query it throws an error. I am trying two ways to prepared statement query.

One is with the use of ? in parameters

```
SELECT b.*,p.value,d.value as dps 
FROM emp b,
     dept p,
     salary d 
where projectid= ? 
  and p.id= ? 
  and d.id= ?
```

2nd one is with the use of named parameter

```
SELECT b.*,p.value,d.value as dps 
FROM emp b,
     dept p,
     salary d 
where projectid= :projectid 
  and p.id= :id 
  and d.id= :dps
```

When i am trying to set the parameters

```
psmt.setString(1, projectid);
psmt.setInt(2, id);
psmt.setInt(3, dps);
```

It throws an error

> "can't use query methods that take a query string on a
>   preparedstatement"

is there any jar file to add in project lib folder if i am using `psmt.setString("projectid",projectid);` again it throws an error.

Comment: How are you executing the query?

Comment: You need to call `ps.executeQuery();` not `ps.executeQuery("My query here");`. The query with the placeholders is already defined at `con.prepareStatement("My query here");` and `PreparedStatement` only allows you to call `executeQuery()` without any parameters.

Comment: Why aren't you joining those tables`?